# Restrict product purchase based on location (option value)

Tags: opencart

I have a little complicated requirement.
I need to sell few products only in particular city. So, I created a 'select' option for that product and added my city name and set other option as 'outside city'. Now, customer should not be able to purchase the product or add it to the cart if he selects 'outside city' as option.

I tried searching for solution but couldn't find one. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint. When adding options in the select menu just add "city name" only and then you need to edit the appropriate template and change the words  **--please select--** to 'outside city'. Once you do this the script will NOT allow the user to proceed unless he chooses the city name.[image: see image]